# Unable to fully install and import Modin Package

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, modin

I am trying to use the `modin` package to speed up my pandas dataframe calculations.
In short, the installation has not been as straightforward as `pip install modin`

When simply running `pip install modin` everything seems to be going fine (except for the pip upgrade warnings). All good so far...

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3; however, version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(base) C:\Users\Merv Merzoug>pip install modin
Requirement already satisfied: modin in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas==0.25.1 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from modin) (0.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas==0.25.1->modin) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas==0.25.1->modin) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\merv merzoug\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pandas==0.25.1->modin) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas==0.25.1->modin) (1.12.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3; however, version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Then I try to merely import the package: `import modin.pandas as pd` as per the docs and I get the following traceback:

```
ImportError: Please `pip install modin[dask] to install compatible Dask version.
```

Okay... so I do what they tell me to. Run `pip install modin[dask]` and I receive the following...

```
    (base) C:\Users\Merv Merzoug>pip install modin[dask]
Requirement already satisfied: modin[dask] in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas==0.25.1 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from modin[dask]) (0.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dask>=2.1.0; extra == "dask" in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from modin[dask]) (2.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask" in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from modin[dask]) (2.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas==0.25.1->modin[dask]) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas==0.25.1->modin[dask]) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\merv merzoug\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pandas==0.25.1->modin[dask]) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers!=2.0.0,!=2.0.1 in c:\users\merv merzoug\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (1.5.9)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=5 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zict>=0.1.3 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.0 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (5.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=0.2.2 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=6.6 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tblib in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.7.4 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas==0.25.1->modin[dask]) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: heapdict in c:\users\merv merzoug\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from zict>=0.1.3->distributed>=2.3.2; extra == "dask"->modin[dask]) (1.0.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3; however, version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Okay, fine, looks like I already have all that installed... let's try to import again...

```
import modin.pandas as pd
```

and that yields the same traceback:

```
ImportError: Please `pip install modin[dask] to install compatible Dask version.
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Comment: try using quotes like in the [docs](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-specific-dependency-sets) `pip install "modin[dask]"` And look at the `Ray` dependency if you are on window

Comment: Nice catch @Chris, the quotes were missing on the repo README

Answer (score 11):

Before the import of modin you have to define the Compute Engine.

Try this (as stated in the github project page of modin):

```
import os

#USE ONLY ONE OF THESE:

os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "ray"  # Modin will use Ray
os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "dask"  # Modin will use Dask

import modin.pandas as pd
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check out a similar question, [Modin conflicts with dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67555760/modin-conflicts-with-dask) to install modin and import the package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in colab, try using the following commands:

```
!pip install -U ipykernel
!pip install modin[dask]
```

If you are getting the same error while importing after running the above command, try restarting the kernel and importing again.

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/881).