# Modin conflicts with dask

Tags: pandas, dask, modin, intel-modin

I'm trying modin, but keep getting an error:

```
import modin.pandas as md
import pandas as pd

PATH = 'file.csv'

%%time
df = pd.read_csv(PATH)

%%time
mdf = md.read_csv(PATH)
```

error:

> UserWarning: Dask execution environment not yet initialized. Initializing...
> To remove this warning, run the following python code before doing dataframe operations:

```
from distributed import Client

client = Client()
```

> Task exception was never retrieved
> future: <Task finished name='Task-8' coro=<_wrap_awaitable() done, defined at C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:683> exception=ImportError("cannot import name 'Popen' from partially initialized module 'multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py)")>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 690, in _wrap_awaitable
> return (yield from awaitable.**await**())
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 290, in _
> await self.start()
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\distributed\nanny.py", line 295, in start
> response = await self.instantiate()
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\distributed\nanny.py", line 378, in instantiate
> result = await self.process.start()
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\distributed\nanny.py", line 575, in start
> await self.process.start()
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\distributed\process.py", line 34, in _call_and_set_future
> res = func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\distributed\process.py", line 202, in _start
> process.start()
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
> self._popen = self._Popen(self)
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
> return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
> File "C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 326, in _Popen
> from .popen_spawn_win32 import Popen
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Popen' from partially initialized module 'multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py)
> '''

I have a popen version 0.1.20 if it is of any help.
Someone on SO suggested to try the thing in error message - import dask.distributed and start the client, but it didn't help.

Any help is much appreciated.

ps. I wanted to try modin a few weeks ago but installation wasn't at all straightforward, with lots of errors, mostly with ray and dask imports. I managed to make dask to work somehow, not modin. And started to learn its api. Now I decided to give it another try since I figured dask was working fine, but no, still some import errors and whats not.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that modin is automatically creating a dask local cluster of processes. Unfortunately, each of those is importing your script, so that they can understand the defined variables - and each is also trying to then start a new dask local cluster.

You should try to put your code in a function, and calling that function from a block protected by

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Answer (score 2):

Modin using Dask execution engine can be installed using following steps.

```
    pip install "modin[dask]" # Install Modin dependencies and Dask to run on Dask
```

If you want to choose a specific compute engine to run on, you can set the environment variable MODIN_ENGINE and Modin will do computation with that engine:

```
    import os
    os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "dask"  # Modin will use Dask
    import modin.pandas as pd
```

Also, initialize Dask environment before performing any dataframe operations using below commands.

```
    from distributed import Client
    client = Client()
```

Please check out Intel Distribution of Modin (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/distribution-of-modin.html#gs.14j7r0) and Modin official page (https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for installation issues and to accelerate pandas workflow on Intel architectures.