# How do I fix modin pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, modin

Basically my code in python is this:

```
import os
from distributed import Client
client = Client()
os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "dask"
import modin.pandas as pd
```

when I run it on python it says `dask execution environment not yet initialized`. What is the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67555760/modin-conflicts-with-dask

Comment: Please do check out the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67555760/modin-conflicts-with-dask/74295537#74295537 to fix modin.